# Django Rest Framework - related fields as nested objects for GET and pk for POST only

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my app which use DRF, I want to use model serializer with multiple related objects.

**models.py:**

```
class JobType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=250)

class Offer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    job_type = models.ForeignKey(JobType, null=False)
    salary = models.DecimalField(null=False, max_digits=8,
                                  decimal_places=2)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class JobTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobType
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job_type = JobTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = (
            'salary', 'job_type', 'user'
        )
```

**views.py:**

```
class SalaryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Salary.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SalaryFullSerializer
```

What I want to achieve:
when I do **GET request** on my api/offers I want to have something like:

```
[
    {
        "salary": 1000,
        "user: 1,
        "job_type": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Developer",
        }
    }
]
```

so, basically, when **GET offers** is made, I want to have nested related object with all it's properties.

On other hand, when **POST offers** is made, I want to limit JobType choices.

When I've removed `job_type = JobTypeSerializer()` from OfferSerializer I had nice dropdown with available choices (in DRF debug). But it caused that GET on offers returned only JobOffer's ID in results.

How can I achieve desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different serializer for **POST** and **GET** requests.
Override `get_serializer_class`

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        return SalaryPostSerializer
    return SalaryFullSerializer
```

Comment: Where should I override that method?

Comment: You can do it in view class `SalaryViewSet`